# Why Euler-Lagrange Theorem gives the optimal control law?

Tags: orbital-motion, optimization

Can anyone explain me in simple language why applying Euler-Lagrange Theorem on Hamiltonian equations gives the optimal control law?
I am specifically talking about trajectory optimization problems where a control "u" needs to be find to optimize the performance index.